# Django: How can I add meta tags for social media?

Tags: django, facebook, meta-tags

I'm working on a Django template that I want to add social media meta tags (like meta property="go:title", meta property="og:description"..). I want to add these meta tags in the **head** of this template's page.

This template however extends the base.html which already has meta tags in it's **head**. So in the first line of this template there is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

I have all the social media meta tags in a partial called *meta-tags-social-share.html*

Is there a way to just extend the **head** of this page with my partial, so that the social media tags are in the **head**?

Comment: you just want to add it to only one page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [blocks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance). In your `meta-tags-social-share.html` add this:

```
{% block extra_head_tags %}
<meta .../>
{% endblock %}
```

In your `base.html` inside the `<head></head>` pair of tags add this line:

```
{% block extra_head_tags %}{% endblock %}
```