# Django: How to Add Meta Tags to Multiple Pages?

Tags: python, html, css, django, seo

Here is a link for a similar question: [Django: How can I add meta tags for social media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619978/django-how-can-i-add-meta-tags-for-social-media)

This question only addresses how to add meta tags if there is only child class, now if there's multiple children that contain the

```
{% block extra_head_tags %}
<meta .../>
{% endblock %}
```

how would I implement this?

Here is a sample structure:

```
 - Base UI.html (contains {% block extra_head_tags %}{% endblock %} )
 
    - Child1.html(contains 
    {% block extra_head_tags %}
       <meta CONTENT1/>
    {% endblock %}
    
    - Child2.html (contains 
    {% block extra_head_tags %}
       <meta CONTENT2/>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation on template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) says:

> If you need to get the **content** of the block **from the parent template, the `{{ block.super }}`** variable will do the trick.

You thus can implement `Child1.html` as:

```
{% block extra_head_tags %}
    {{ block.super }}
       <meta CONTENT1/>
{% endblock %}
```

If you thus added meta information in the "parent template", these will show up in the rendering of the "child template" as well.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. What I'm asking is if the parent would have an empty block called extra_block_tags that will be overwritten by one child at a time. If there are multiple children, how can we implement it so that no errors occur?

Comment: @AngelaRubchinksy: but that makes no sense, each template where you redefine the block will override that block from its parent (or ancestor if there are multiple ones). It will thus only render *that* template (with its ancestors), and not look at other templates. If you want to set the tags on all pages, you need to add the tags to a model, and then enumerate over that model to specify all tags.